# Solving second order differential equation - Important for thesis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Thank you so much in advance for any help that you might give me. I'm stuck and can't solve the following equation

$y(x)+C_1y'(x) x+C_2 y''(x)x²=0$

Where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants.

More importantly, 
$-r y(x)+\theta (\mu - x)y'(x)+\frac{\sigma ²}{2}y''(x)x²=0$
Any help?

Comment: Does $\theta$ denote the Heaviside function?

Comment: Are you sure that the first term in the first DE is $y'(x)$ ? Could it be $y(x)$ instead ?

Comment: i'm sure it must be $$y(x)$$

Comment: Is there a $x^2$ missing in the 2nd eq?

Comment: For the first one,  if $y$ is smooth, use the Maclaurin series of $y(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first equation:

$0
=y(x)+cy'(x) x+d y''(x)x^2
$.

Let
$y(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n
$.

$y'(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}
$
so
$cxy'(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} cna_nx^{n}
$.

$y''(x)
=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}
$
so
$dx^2y''(x)
=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} dn(n-1)a_nx^{n}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=y(x)+cy'(x) x+d y''(x)x^2\\
&=a_0+a_1x+ca_1x +\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^n(1+cn+dn(n-1))\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore, no solution of this type.

If $y = ax^b$,
$cxy' = abcx^{b}$
and
$dx^2y'' = ab(b-1)dx^{b}$,
so
$0
=x^b(a+abc+ab(b-1)d)
=ax^b(1+bc+b(b-1)d)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=1+bc+b(b-1)d\\
&=1+bc-bd+b^2d\\
&=1+b(c-d)+b^2d\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $d \ne 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
b
&=\frac{d-c\pm\sqrt{(c-d)^2-4d}}{2d}\\
&=\frac{d-c\pm\sqrt{c^2-6cd+d^2}}{2d}\\
&=\frac{1-r\pm\sqrt{r^2-6r+1}}{2}
\qquad\text{where }r = \frac{c}{d}\\
\end{array}
$

If $d = 0$,
$b = -\frac1{c}
$.

Comment: If there is a $n$ such that $1+cn+dn(n-1)=0$, the series give the solution $y=a x^n$.